# android: myViewPager cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, android-viewpager

In my MainActivity i have this code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;




public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    myViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);


    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

        case 2: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
        case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
        case 0: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
        default: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }       
}
}
```

The fragments are working fine and when i run MainActivity i want to open the SecondFragment first, so i tried using:

```
myViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

But then i get the error "myViewPager cannot be resolved", i have tried updating SDK and adding support library, but nothing seems to help, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `myViewPager ` belong to which  `layout `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not declared  `myViewPager` and you also need to initialize it before `myViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);`.

You probably meant `pager.setCurrentItem(1);`

Comment: thanks for fast answer, how do i declare it? im quite new to java coding :)

Comment: @da_st it should probably be `pager.setCurrentItem(1);` after this `ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager)`

Comment: i changed it to pager.setCurrentItem(1); and now the error is: "pager cannot be resolved" :/

Comment: oh never mind now it works! :) i forgot to set it after ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager). thanks :)